# Using charts in web application (negative value in bar chart)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-applications

I want to use bar chart in web application.

I have searched many libraries including google code, and many but many do not support negative values for bar charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of "hacks" to display negative values with the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/):

[image: Negative numbers in the Google Chart API]

> The above chart was generated using: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chd=t:50,50,50,30,50|0,0,0,20,0|20,10,30,0,30&chco=00000000,ff0000,0000ff&chs=200x125&chg=0,51,1,0&chxt=y&chxl=0%3a|-50|0|50

You may want to check the following article for further reading about this workaround:

- [Negative numbers in the Google Chart API](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2007/12/08/negative-numbers-in-the-google-chart-api)

Answer (score 1):

**[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)** is more than capable of displaying negative values. Have a look at [this example](http://jsbin.com/odamo) I whipped up.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) supports them as long as you set the graph scale accordingly, I think.

[gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) is also supposed to support them but there was a bug at some point and I don't know if it's fixed.